# Laptop won't sleep when lid is closed

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

I have ASUS ROG and it won't go to sleep when I close the lid. I can still hear the music playing. I checked "Choose what closing the lid does" and I have "sleep". My old laptop sleeps automatically when I left it open for hours or when I close the lid. I don't know why this doesn't. I kinda don't like shutting it down when I'm doing projects because I have a lot of windows open (multi tasking).
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdmqM.png)

Comment: Update the BIOS and the ASUS Power Driver.  Restart, check the settings and try again